# Redondear con 2 decimales en C++

Tags: c++

En el **HUD** de mi juego muestro el tiempo (`tipo: float`), pero necesito que sea `mm:ss`, es decir, 2 decimales después de la coma.

```
float timeReal = 12.342334;

float timeRedondeado = ...
```

Como puedo guardarlo con 2 decimales?

Comment: No me queda claro ¿Necesitas **guardar** el valor con precisión de 2 decimales o necesitas **mostrar** el valor con precisión de 2 decimales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Cómo puedo guardarlo con 2 decimales?

No puedes.

---

#### Los números con decimales no funcionan así.

Los números en coma flotante no guardan valores hasta cierto número de decimales si no que guardan un número expresado en índice y exponente guardado de forma binaria.

En C++ se sigue el [estándar del IEEE para aritmética en coma flotante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante) en que cada número está representado de la siguiente manera:

> **r** = **c** × **b<sup>e</sup>**

Siendo:

- **c** El [coeficiente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coeficiente_(matem%C3%A1ticas)) del número.
- **b** La [base](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potenciaci%C3%B3n).
- **e** El [exponente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potenciaci%C3%B3n) entero, el cual eleva la base a una potencia.

Así pues, el número -12,345 (**r**) podría representarse como -12345 (**b**) × 10<sup>-3</sup> (**e**).

#### Cambia de estrategia.

> En el HUD de mi juego muestro el tiempo (`tipo: float`), pero necesito que sea `mm:ss`, es decir, 2 decimales después de la coma.

Tienes un problema de concepto: los segundos no son decimales de minutos (un minuto no es 1/10 de hora si no 1/60) así que deberías hacer conversiones de tiempo teniendo la diferente proporción:

- 0,75 minutos son 45 segundos.
- 0,5 minutos son 30 segundos.
- 0,33 minutos son 20 segundos.
- 0,2 minutos son 12 segundos.
- 0,1 minutos son 6 segundos.
- ...

Pero tranquilo, no necesitas hacer ninguna conversión, C++ dispone de la librería [`<chrono>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) que te permite trabajar con unidades de tiempo:

```
auto tiempo = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto formato = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&formato), "%M:%S");
```

El código anterior captura la hora actual (en la variable `tiempo`) y le aplica el formato `mm:ss` usando [`std::put_time`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time), para obtener la cadena de caracteres llama a [`stringstream::str`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str).

Answer (score 0):

**[A]** Si quieres mantener el número, puedes usar alguna de las siguientes opciones:

1) Usando la sintaxis que empleamos en C, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
printf("%.2lf", timeReal");
```

Si deseas guardar el dato usa sprintf.

2) Otra opción es la que te muestro a continuación con setprecision:

```
#include <iomanip>

cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << timeReal << endl;
```

En ambos casos el redondeo te lo va a efectuar de cara a la salida de datos. la variable seguirá igual.

**[B]** Si lo que quieres es operar con las cantidades redondeadas, puedes recurrir al método round() de la librería math.

1. Multiplica por 100
2. Redondea el resultado con round()
3. Divide por 100